# Push Notifcation Woes with Titanium & XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, titanium, apple-push-notifications

I am using Titanium 2.0.2 to create an iPhone app which must, amongst other things, be able to receive push notifications. I have done the following

a. Created the AppID in my Apple Developer account
b. Configured the AppID for Push
c. Created a new provisioning profile using the newly created AppID
d. For good measure edited that profile - given that I have heard reports that the first time round it does not pick up the AppID Push info correctly

Armed with all of that I have proceeded to register my app for Push using Ti.Network.registerForPUshNotifications and coded the success, error and callback methods. I have closely followed the example in the Titanium Kitchen Sink demo.

Having done all this I had fully expected one of the following outcomes

1. Registration succeeds and I get the alert message I have stuck in the Success callback.
2. Registration fails and I get the alert message in my Error callback

Much to my surprise nothing happens at all - it is like the registerForPushNotifications call goes out into the ether and is well...gone

To be doubly sure I created a simple XCode project following the excellent tutorial at http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/tutorial-ios-push-notification-services-for-beginners/. The app registers with APNS and I trap the assigned remoteDeviceUUID using my iPad and http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/consolelog/id415116252?mt=8.  I have then adapted the simplepush.php script from ManicDev and run it off my local WAMP server.  It gets through to APNS and deposits my very first PUSH message.  But it never arrives on my iPad!

For the sake of completeness I should mention that I am getting a development build onto my iPad with the help of TestFlightApp.

So what am I doing wrong here?

a. Why does Titanium simply not want to do anything in response to RegisterForPushNotifications?
b. Wny does my sample XCode app never get the Push notification?

I would hugely appreciate any help on this one.

Answer (score 1):

A note for anyone running into this post.  Beware of testing Push notifications on your iPad behind a WiFi firewall router.  Most routers block access to the port used by APNS.  I spent way too much time trying to find a "bug" in my code only to discover that there wasn't one.  Putting the device in the DMZ on your router might help but is not reliable - at least not with my Sitecom router.

Answer (score 0):

The adhoc builds that Test Flight uses are "Production" in terms of the push notifications not development ones so mostly likely your server needs to be configured with the Production APNS server keys to get it to work.